# How to put ubuntu into Performance mode

Tags: 14.04

Is there any command i should use to do this or am i just out of luck?  have looked at Jupiter but it seems to be obsolete. Is there another program i could install? If so please tell me the name of it...

Also, I am trying to do this so I can game on my laptop again. I am trying to play Borderlands The Pre Sequel.  Not sure if that information will help, but I will add it just in case.

1. Jupiter is not supported
2. I have no idea what i am doing.

(What do I have to do to submit this question!?!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install cpu-freq.

It has four options: Conservative, Ondemand,Powersave, Performance.

```
(sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq)
```

Comment: How do I activate the program?

Comment: After you install it automatically appears on the top panel as soon as you log out and log in.

Comment: Good one!  And an upvote!